# How to use tocloft with revtex without changing \tableofcontents formatting

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, revtex

I need to create a custom "list of ..." in my document. As I search around the intertubes, I'm told to use the `tocloft` package. The documentation seems promising. However, when I load the package, the formatting for my existing table of contents gets all messed up.

**Is there a way to use `tocloft` to create a custom "list of" without modifying the formatting for the table of contents?**

Below is an example that shows what happens. Note that when the `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}` line is commented, out the table of contents is formatted differently. Note, I can't get it to compile without the `titles` option to the `tocloft` package.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,amsmath,amssymb,10pt,superscriptaddress,aps,rmp,letterpaper,fleqn,floatfix]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\section{Section 1 }
\section{Section 2 }
\section{Section 3 }
\section{Section 4 }
\section{Section 5 }
\end{document}
```

Comment: `tocloft` generates individual `\cftZ...` commands (see the manual) for adjusting the 'personal' `\listof....` settings. Those settings do not interfere with the regular ToC etc. Please show a compilable document such we can figure out!

Comment: `tocloft` only changes the settings if you tell it to. Have you read the `tocloft` documentation (try `texdoc tocloft`) , in particular section 2.4 New list of... ?

Comment: I have read the documentation, even section 2.4. However, merely loading the package messes up the formatting of my document. I'll try and post an example later today.

Comment: Have you tried loading the `tocloft` package with the option `titles` (see section 2.1 of the package's user guide)?

Comment: @Mico yes I have tried that. I was hoping that was the solution.

Comment: @jlconlin: Since Mico's proposition did not work for you (why???) I think you should post your compilable example.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. I've added an example to my original question.

Comment: It would have been really useful if you had mentioned sooner which document class you use. The `revtex` family of document classes and the `tocloft` package are known not to get along very well. In short, if you must use the `revtex4-1` document class, you can't use `tocloft`.

Comment: @mico Sorry about that. I didn't know there was a conflict between those two packages.